# Automatically identifying speech disfluencies from audio recordings

Tags: speech-processing, speech-recognition, speech

I want to automatically identify speech disfluencies (e.g. um(s) and uh(s) ) from my speech recordings. I am a bit surprised I couldn't find any disfluency detection models using speech only. I know some commercial cloud speech2text services label disfluencies automatically, but I cannot afford to use it. Does anyone know any speech-only disfluency detection I could use, or if any offline speech2text models output speech disfluencies too?

The alternative is to obtain the text transcripts then apply a forced alignment model which some output speech disfluencies.

Thanks! Any suggestions would be welcomed!

Comment: So, you're, um, looking for a, uh, solution to a problem rather than, err, looking to understand, ah, how to build one?

Comment: You're right Tim, I am looking for a off-the-shelf solution. I have spent some time looking for relevant studies on this problem but seems most of the papers are tackling it from a linguistic perspective.